# Why does sudo command take long to execute?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo

I've been picking up Linux (Fedora 10, then 11) over the past few months (and enjoying it immensely-- it's like discovering computers all over again, so many things to learn).

I've added my user to the last line of the `/etc/sudoers` file as shown below, so that I don't get asked for my password when I execute the `sudo` command:

```
MyUserName ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Now every time I execute a command using `sudo`, it pauses a noticeable amount of time before actually performing the task (~10 seconds).  Why might this be and how might I fix this?  I'm running Sudo version 1.7.1 on Fedora 11 x86 64.

Comment: Technically this counts as editing a script, right?  Isn't a script a program?

Comment: NOPASSWD: is considered a security risk and defeats the purpose of having to use sudo in the first place.

Comment: I can buy that, but the issue still remains as to why it takes so long.

Comment: Where does this machine get is users and authentication from? LDAP, possibly with Kerberos perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Every single time I use sudo it hangs before completing](http://serverfault.com/questions/65370/every-single-time-i-use-sudo-it-hangs-before-completing)

Comment: Facing the same issue, with or without `NOPASSWD` (also irrelevant advice in reference to the question).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

I asked this question over on SO and it got moved here.  That said I no longer have the ability to edit the question as if I owned it, or even accept the correct answer, but this turned out to be the true reason why and how to solve it:

[Found here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/fedora-11-sudo-has-a-20-second-start-delay-732291/#post3575840)  User "rohandhruva" on there gives the right answer:

> This happens if you change the
>   hostname during the install process.
>
> To solve the problem, edit the file
>   /etc/hosts
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 <ADD_YOURS_HERE> 
> ::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 <ADD_YOURS_HERE>
> ```

Comment: Quite right.  Somewhat surprising that distros like Fedora don't edit /etc/hosts if you change your hostname at install time, but whatever.  That's open source for you!

Comment: This fixed my slow sudo usage, thanks!  I edited /etc/hostname, and just forgot to edit the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Adding your Hostname to the 127.0.0.1 or ::1 line can cause certain server related software from binding to the right Hostname/IP/interface. One such example is Cloudera Manager, the hadoop services get the wrong Hostname and confuse CM because they all resolve to localhost. I suggest reading other answer below for a possible solution. This may or may not cause issues to a standalone workstation which will have no other computers connecting to it.

Comment: It can also be /etc/nsswitch.conf (for similar reasons).  Mine was set to "hosts: dns files" and so it was looking up my hostname on a DNS server with a long timeout.  I changed it to "hosts: files dns" and so now it'll look in /etc/hosts first.  Thanks for this answer, which led me to look in nsswitch.conf!

Comment: That's ridiculous that this was the solution. Why in the world does the `sudo` command have to look at the hostname in order to work? What does my hostname have to do with `sudo echo hello`? Anyways, thanks for the answer

Comment: I am running CentOS 6.x and the issue has been `rsyslog` needing to be restarted. Full answer below from @galgalesh

Comment: To avoid the delay when editing /etc/hosts, you can run `sudoedit -h localhost /etc/hosts` (or `sudo -h localhost vi /etc/hosts` or whatever if you don't have $EDITOR set).

Comment: Why does sudo do this? Because it's multiuser configuration can be set by host. You can disable this with a `Defaults !fqdn` careful if you are actually relying on hostnames in sudoers instead of ALL

Comment: I have tried this and it didn't resolve the issue for me with Centos 7 in AWS instances.  Is it possible we should try restarting some service to apply the change?

Answer (score 29):

Check that your syslog daemon is working correctly; this caused the issue for me.

Run the following command

```
logger 'Hello world'
```

1. Does the command return within a reasonable amount of time?
2. Does 'Hello world' show up in `/var/log/syslog`?

If this is not the case, the syslog daemon has crashed. Restarting it should fix your problem.

Comment: Surprisingly that was the problem for me. Who would have thought it. The solution for me was just to restart syslog. `service rsyslog restart`

Comment: Same here. `service rsyslog restart` fixed my slow sudo commands.

Comment: Surprisingly that was the problem for me. Before that, the whole request for the server is so slowly.  I just want to know why?

Answer (score 16):

Is one of the files/directories it needs to read on a networked mount, or is it somehow triggering reading from a slow usb device?  Try strace and see where it's slow; if it goes by too fast, do

```
sudo strace -r -o trace.log sudo echo hi
```

Each line will start with the time taken since entering the previous syscall.

(The initial sudo seems to be necessary; I don't know how much that will perturb the results.)

Comment: Thx.  This is on the HDD tho, no USB or network drive.

Comment: @Cuga: and what did you learn from strace?

Comment: @oligofren: you need to do sudo strace

Answer (score 13):

I recently found that I had the same problem. There had been no sudo delay and then all of a sudden, about a 10-20 second delay.  I determined the specific issue using:

```
 1. chmod u+s /usr/sbin/strace  (as the root user)
```

As yourself:

```
 1. sudo -K
 2. strace sudo /bin/tcsh
```

And then find where the system calls are hanging.

In MY case, I found that it was hanging on a DNS translation, apparently one of the DNSen in my list on `/etc/resolv.conf` was very buzy or gone bad.  So I changed the resolution order and poof things worked quickly again.

Comment: Best answer (for me)! Found out my DBus Broker was crashing on network disconnect and sudo/KDE was timing out on connecting to it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I also had to undo a previous change to the `hosts` line in   my /etc/nsswitch.conf. I had added "resolve dns" as a prefix to the `hosts` value. When I removed this prefix, sudo was fast again.

Answer (score 10):

I hade the same problem, I checked /var/log/auth.log and syslog for errors. Turns out that my LDAP server could not be reached and it slowed down everything.

I did not use LDAP based auth anymore, so I removed all "ldap" references from /etc/nsswitch.conf

Since then everything works like a charm again.

Comment: Why do you post an obviously unrelated answer (the OP didn't use LDAP) to a five year old question?

Comment: Because it might help anyone. I checked all the things that were mentioned here, but nothing helped. Someone else might be focused into looking into the right direction with my answer by checking whether he has any LDAP connection issues as the underlying reason of the slow and unresponsive sudo command. It is as relevant as the DNS-related answers in that something behind the covers is at fault which is not directly visible to the user. I consider this site as a general source of knowledge and not just as a single question/answer type of website. It is about collecting relevant knowledge.

Comment: Also who in the blue hell are you to discredit my help. This site works because sharing knowledge is incentivized, not because people are downvoted. If you dont like it, then you entitled to ignoring it.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the hostname (that was configured in `/etc/sysconfig/network`) didn't exist in `/etc/hosts` file; so upon adding it to the aforementioned file, the file opens promptly.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about Fedora, but I've used other systems where sudo would check
where you're logged in from, which if your DNS isn't set up well can take ages
to timeout. This can also be seen when SSH'ing in to the machine - it takes
ages to come up with a prompt.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, I fixed it by placing both the hostname (e.g. mybox) and the full output of the hostname command (mybox.mydomain.com).  This cleared it right up.  Went from 2 minutes to open /etc/hosts to instantaneous access.

Answer (score 3):

### SELinux case

If the same sudo command is **slow only in a daemon** and fast on the command line, then it is caused by **SELinux** the most probably. (SELinux = NSA Security-Enhanced Linux kernel module, enabled in Fedora by default.)

A typical case is a http server and a special script for server management, restricted in `sudoers`:

```
apache ALL=(root_or_user) NOPASSWD: /full/path/the_safe_command
```

It is typical in this case that nothing about SELinux is reported in the audit log `ausearch -m avc -ts today`, but the script is going fast if we temporarily disable enforcing by `setenforce 0`. (and then back enable by `setenforce 1`)

The only relevant messages in the system log (journalcrl) are these after the delay 25 seconds:

> ... sudo[...] pam_systemd(sudo:session): Failed to create session: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
>   ... sudo[...]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Logging of all silented "dont-audit" SElinux messages can be enabled by `semodule -DB` and disabled again by `semodule -B`.
(I hope that I write soon a SELinux policy module soon for this case here or a method from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/617766/57359) can be used.)

Comment: Thank you for this piece of information. From the information here, I was then able to find a [related article](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0102049) that noted the possibility of `fprintd` (the fingerprint authentication) the culprit. Removing `fprintd` and `fprintd-pam` resolved the issue for me.

Comment: @KevinO Pleased that it helped you to find a solution. I knew however that my problem was very specific and that my contribution to the question should be only the method how to diagnose or exclude a suspicion about SELinux.

Comment: I absolutely gave it a +1! It was the message bus that led to a solution. I had looked a couple of times on sudo slow, but yours was the clue I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Check your /etc/hosts file and make sure you have an entry for 127.0.0.1

([source](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=210503))

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the sample `sudoers` file I have, I believe there is supposed to be a space after the `NOPASSWD:` bit.

Comment: I added a space, but it still has the lag.  Thx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing any host problems make sure you clear any bad DNS cache if you are running a DNS caching application like nscd:

```
/etc/init.d/nscd force-reload
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was krb5-user/config/locales being installed.  I noticed this by examining /var/log/auth.log. Using apt-get remove to uninstall those packages fixed it.  Don't remove those packages if you are on a computer requiring kerberos (pam_krb5) obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Using strace pointed me to dbus.

```
# Run strace with timestamp and output file 
strace -t -o /tmp/strace.txt sudo ls
```

In the output file, I see a connect call to file `/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`, and a Timeout message with the same file descriptor `fd=7`

```
10:20:16 connect(7, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 29) = 0
...
10:20:16 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 0 (Timeout)                                                                                                                                                     
10:20:41 sendmsg(7, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="l\1\1\1\204\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/fre"..., iov_len=144}, {iov_base="\177\0\0\0type='signal',sender='net.re"..., iov_len=132}], msg_iovlen=2, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 276
```

Password prompt appeared at 10:20:41, 25 seconds after command is run. Restarting messagebus service fixed the issue:

```
systemctl restart messagebus
```

Comment: I have this error `sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using LDAP for authentication?

If so you probably want to use bind policy soft. In /etc/ldap/ldap.conf (or /etc/ldap.conf):

```
bind_policy soft
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have some kind of timeout in your authentication chain. Check how sudo tries to authenticate and watch for bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

**Systemd Case**

For me, my system had run out of memory and a lot of processes crashed. My system is based around systemd and something in there had crashed. It's hard for me to remember everything I did, but:

- `systemctl status <any.service>` would timeout
- I couldn't `sudo reboot` (systemd based)

**Solution**

A restart fixed my issue, but for me was just a bandaid. You still need to find out why you ran out of memory/crashed.

Answer (score 0):

HTH and FWIW I **resolved the issue by temporarily removing `systemd` from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`**.  The error message which showed up in `/var/log/auth.log` was something like `dbus-daemon[1818]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)`

> I do not recommend running systems in this state because I do not have any idea what unwanted side effects this may have.
>
> This, however, is my mitigation, to be able to continue to keep the system usable until some proper monitored reboot slot becomes available in the perhaps distant future.

Before:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

after

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

The problem affected all login types, not only `sudo` or `ssh`.  The 25 second delay prevented the management system from properly doing system maintenance, the `ssh` delay made important remote scripts time out.  Also various other services started to fail because the watchdogs did not like the imposed delay of simple things like `su`.

After this change everything seems to be back normal now.
(It is a plain headless server, so no X11 or similar is needed.)

FYI:

The problem started to show up after the update updated SystemD (AKA init).  We do not need nor use any SystemD specifics here (yet), hence I think, there is no much drawback *here* by removing SystemD in that config for the time being.  YMMV.