# SELinux blocking sudo from zabbix_agentd

Tags: centos, sudo, selinux, zabbix

I have a custom user parameter for Zabbix that calls a hardware RAID CLI tool (arcconf / megacli) and checks if any arrays are degraded. Since these tools are root-only, I have configured sudoers to allow the zabbix user access without password:

```
Defaults:zabbix !requiretty
Cmnd_Alias ZABBIX_MEGACLI_CMDS = /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LDInfo -Lall -aALL
zabbix  ALL     = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ZABBIX_MEGACLI_CMDS
```

On CentOS 5 the zabbix_agentd ran unconfined and all was well. On CentOS 6 the agent now runs in a separate zabbix_agent_t domain. This caused problems. Initially the sudo binary itself could not be executed but I have added this policy:

```
sudo_exec(zabbix_agent_t)
```

Now it dies in a different way:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1407137597.193:157): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=3145 comm="sudo" scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:zabbix_agent_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:zabbix_agent_t:s0 tclass=unix_dgram_socket
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1407137597.193:157): arch=c000003e syscall=41 success=no exit=-13 a0=1 a1=80002 a2=0 a3=1 items=0 ppid=3121 pid=3145 auid=0 uid=496 gid=495 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=495 sgid=495 fsgid=495 tty=(none) ses=3 comm="sudo" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:zabbix_agent_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1407137597.193:158): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=3145 comm="sudo" scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:zabbix_agent_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:zabbix_agent_t:s0 tclass=netlink_audit_socket
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1407137597.193:158): arch=c000003e syscall=41 success=no exit=-13 a0=10 a1=3 a2=9 a3=7fffce049a20 items=0 ppid=3121 pid=3145 auid=0 uid=496 gid=495 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=495 sgid=495 fsgid=495 tty=(none) ses=3 comm="sudo" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:zabbix_agent_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Is this the right approach to do things? What other policies can I add so zabbix_agent_t can run sudo? If sudo works will it still be confined within zabbix_agent_t domain or should I add e.g. `TYPE=unconfined_t` to the sudoers line? Should I adopt https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=917157 and s/nrpe_t/zabbix_agent_t/?

EDIT:

Not sure if this is the best idea but...

```
sudo_exec(zabbix_agent_t)
domtrans_pattern(zabbix_agent_t, sudo_exec_t, unconfined_t)
```

seems to work. I suppose the worst case is it falls back on the security of sudo and the sudoers files.

Comment: can you explain where you added the sudo_exec command?

Comment: It's a local policy module (.te file) - please refer to the docs on how to use it https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-allowing_access_audit2allow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to handle this is to collect all the information about what access the program needs, and then explicitly allow only that access in a custom policy module.

This is fairly easy to do.

First, you [set the domain permissive](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Permissive_Domains.html), so that SELinux temporarily does not enforce its rules. It will still *log* the denials, and later you will use these logs.

```
semanage permissive -a zabbix_agent_t
```

Next, let the program run and let it do whatever it needs to do. The [audit log](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Raw_Audit_Messages.html) will fill up with what would have been denied, and these logs also show what permissions will need to be granted. Then [view these logs with `ausearch`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Searching_For_and_Viewing_Denials.html).

```
ausearch -r -m avc -ts today
```

We'll [generate a local policy module](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html) containing the necessary permissions. (You need to use the `-r` option with `ausearch` here so that the output can be processed by other scripts.)

If you saw clearly irrelevant entries, redirect the output to a file, and then edit it to remove them. Then use the file here instead.

```
ausearch -r -m avc -ts today | audit2allow -M zabbix_megacli
```

Finally, we install our new local policy module and re-enable SELinux enforcement.

```
semodule -i zabbix_megacli.pp
semanage permissive -d zabbix_agent_t
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. However the permissions required are write and ioctl to disk device nodes. I'm not sure this improves security meaningfully over just using sudo. As a compromise would it be better to have another executable in the middle, labeled appropriately like e.g. nagios_unconfined_plugin_exec_t here: https://mgrepl.fedorapeople.org/Blog/nagios.html ?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a better solution. But nothing of the sort has yet been implemented in the policy, as far as I know. Better have a chat with Dan Walsh, or perhaps your Red Hat rep.

Comment: This worked for me. I believe Zabbix documentation need to be update to include this